# Method to set a char array equal to each other wont work

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

For my homework assignment I am required to use pointers to navigate arrays in c++. The set function I have written to set a private object member variable `char m_make[]` equal to the passed `char[]` is not functioning correctly. When I try and run my program it appears to terminate after I call the `setMake()` function. What am I doing wrong?

Function declaration: (contained in an object called `RentalCar`)
`void setMake(char make[5]);`

Here is the code for `setMake()`:

```
void RentalCar::setMake(char make[5]){
    for(int i = 0; (make+i) != '\0';i++){
        *(m_make+i) = *(make+i);
    }
}
```

When I call `setMake()` no matter what I pass the function the output is `Process returned` followed by a very large number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, you are checking `(make+i) != '\0'` which basically adds `i` to `make` each time you iterate. `make` is the *memory address* of the first character of the array.

With that being said, `(make+i)` will never be `== '\0'` because `(make+i)` is a memory address, and addresses that your program has access to are never NULL which means it is an infinite loop.

You need to use the pointer notation to actually de-reference your `(make+i)` so that it checks the value that is inside the memory `(make+i)` but not the address itself. Means, you have to do:

`*(make + i) != '\0'`

to **get** the value and compare it, just like you are doing to **set** the value:

`*(m_make+i) = *(make+i);`